# How can i echo next and previous custom category from a Taxonomy

Tags: categories, custom-taxonomy

i have create a custom Taxonomy with CPT plugin.
In that taxnomy called test i have 4 categories ( test1, test2, test3, test4 )

When i am in archive page in category test2 i want to echo a simple text and a link to a previous category ( test1 ) and to the next category ( test3)

I have read all solution that i found but none of them works.

Comment: And these terms are ordered by...? Name? ID?

Comment: Lets say name , because by id is wrong , the first has id 3 the second 56 etc.

Comment: I have found this solution https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/222498/is-it-possible-to-get-a-previous-next-taxonomy-term-archive-url  but it does not print anything in my case.  Can someone help me on this?